# SelfPopulatingCache in Ehcache 3.2

Tags: ehcache

`SelfPopulatingCache` is available in `Ehcache version 2.8` but not in version `3.2`. Is there something that gives the same functionality in `version 3.2`?

Answer (score 1):

Ehcache 3.x does not reproduce this concept directly.

However you can perfectly achieve the same result by [using a `CacheLoaderWriter`](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.2/writers.html#implementing-cache-through).
Simply ignore the write-through part by having no-op implementations and implement the `load` and `loadAll` method to perform the logic you find in the Ehcache 2.x `CacheEntryFactory`.

Comment: Not quite the same if you care about cache statistics.  When using a CacheLoaderWriter, statistics will always report a 100% hit rate.